# android LocalBroadcast not received some times randomly

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I am listening for Media mounted and unmounted events as below

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".activity.MediaManagementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL_MOUNTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

When intended events happen, in `onReceive`, an `LocalBroadcast` is sent which should be received in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent localIntent;
        Log.e(TAG+"-FIXME", "intent " + intent.getAction() + " ; data " + intent.getData().toString()+ " ; isSticky? "+isInitialStickyBroadcast() + ""+System.currentTimeMillis());
        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT) |
                intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL) |
                intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)){
            if(intent.getData().toString().contains("udisk"))
                localIntent = new Intent(context.getPackageName() + ".USB.UNAVAILABLE");
            else
                localIntent = new Intent(context.getPackageName() + ".SD.UNAVAILABLE");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
        }else if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            if(intent.getData().toString().contains("udisk"))
                localIntent = new Intent(context.getPackageName() + ".USB.AVAILABLE");
            else
                localIntent = new Intent(context.getPackageName() + ".SD.AVAILABLE");
            //

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
        }

    }
```

And the intent filters and LocalBroadcast registration are done as below

```
    IntentFilter lbmIFilter = new IntentFilter();
        lbmIFilter.addAction(getPackageName() + ".USB.AVAILABLE");
        lbmIFilter.addAction(getPackageName() + ".USB.UNAVAILABLE");
        lbmIFilter.addAction(getPackageName() + ".SD.AVAILABLE");
        lbmIFilter.addAction(getPackageName() + ".SD.UNAVAILABLE");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(getPackageName() + ".USB.AVAILABLE")) {
                    if (!isUSBAvailable()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "FIXME calling onUSBPlugged "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                        usbAvailable = true;
                        onUSBPlugged();
                    }
                } else if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(getPackageName() + ".USB.UNAVAILABLE")) {
                    if (isUSBAvailable()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "FIXME calling onUSBRemoved "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                        usbAvailable = false;
                        onUSBRemoved();
//                        cinemoMediaServer.StopUSBServer();
                    }
                } else if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(getPackageName() + ".SD.UNAVAILABLE")) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "FIXME calling onSDCARDRemoved "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                    onSDCARDRemoved();

                } else if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(getPackageName() + ".SD.AVAILABLE")) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "FIXME calling onSDCARDPlugged "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                    onSDCARDPlugged();

                }
            }
        }, lbmIFilter);
```

The **problem** is that when usb in plugged and unplugged rapidly, `android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT` event is received and `LocalBroadcast` is sent. But the `LocalBroadcast` is not received by receiver in `MainActivity`